# function minimisation in R

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to minimise `fmin` in the function `funmin`, but I'm getting this error message:

> Error in optim(c(1e-13, 10000), funmin, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower =
>   c(1e-16,  :    objective function in optim evaluates to length 5 not 1

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? see code below.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(deSolve)

l <- 0.5 # bone 1/2 thickness (cm)
x_vec <- c(0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.30, 0.45)
A1meas <-    c(0.51, 0.55, 0.64, 0.70, 0.92)

# x_vec <- -x_vec*l
l234 <- 2.8262e-6/(365.25*24*3600)
length_series <- 100

funmin <- function(x) {
  A1_0 <- 0.025 # (238U) at the surface of the bone (disintegrations per second)
  K <- x[1] # D/R diffusion coefficient/volumetric equilibirum constant
  t <- x[2] # age in yr
  t <- t*(365.25*24*3600)

  series238 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  A1calc <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
  i <- 0

  for (x in x_vec){
    for (n in 0:length_series){
      series238[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*exp(-K*((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    }
    sum_series238 <- sum(series238)  
    i <- i+1
    A1calc[i] <- A1_0*(1 - 4/pi*sum_series238)
  }

  fmin <- (A1calc - A1meas)^2
}

optim(c(1e-13, 1e4), funmin, method = "L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(1e-16, 1e3), upper = c(1e-8, 1e6))
```

Answer (score 0):

got it... as the error message said (duh!) the function evaluated has a length of 5 instead of this.
This works: `fmin <- sum((A1calc - A1meas)^2)`